# Check If function exists dynamically

Tags: jquery, function, controller

I need a function to check whether a function in jQuery exists and if that's true this function should be called. If I use below code with an simple name it works, but if i want to check dynamically whether a function exists it doesn't work. Have anybody an idea?

```
function homeController() {
    console.log('in the homecontroller');
}

$('div[class="view"]').each(function() {
        $('#' + this.id).live('pageshow', function() {
            var func = this.id + 'Controller';              
            if($.isFunction(func)) {
                console.log('jquery exists');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: You mean you want to test whether arbitrary JavaScript functions are in the scope? Of course `func` is just a a string in your example, not a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`jQuery.isFunction()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isFunction/) method to check whether an object is a function or not.

```
$('div[class="view"]').each(function() {
        $('#' + this.id).live('pageshow', function() {
            var func = eval(this.id + 'Controller');              
            if($.isFunction(func)) {
                console.log('jquery exists');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need to use `eval` for that, because your `func` is a string.

```
var func = eval(this.id + 'Controller');
if($.isFunction(func)) {
   func();
}
```

Comment: If i use ''eval'' it will execute the function and throws an error when a function does not exists, so i need another way for it.

Comment: If you don't put parentheses `()` at the end it will not execute but only get the value of it.

Comment: I dont put parentheses at the end, but i get still an error in my case "listController" is not defined.

Comment: You can try to use `$.isFunction(window[this.id + 'Controller'])`

Comment: Ok actually this works only if i check for functions which are outside the `$(document).ready(function()..` scope...so i move my functions out and now it works. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

$.isFunction - "Determine if the argument passed is a Javascript function object". Obviously, you are passing a string.

If you wish to check for jQuery plugin than use

```
if (typeof jQuery[yourFunctionName] == 'function') { ..
```

And for general JavaScript function -

```
if(typeof window[yourFunctionName] == 'function') { ..
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out which scope your function is in (or in other words, which object are your functions properties of), and then use

```
if ($.isFunction(scope[func])) {
    ...
}
```

to convert the name of the required function into a reference to that function within the current scope.

That assumes, of course, that your functions are actually *in* some scope.

So if your `homeController()` function has been declared in global scope, it will be a property of the `window.` global object.

However if they've just been declared as an inner function within some other closure they won't have one.

Answer (score 0):

```
function doIt(callback) {

    console.log('Did it');

    typeof callback === 'function' && callback();

}
```

This only executes the callback if the function exists. You can pull that line from this function and use it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection-java can also be used to check whether a method or a field or a class exists or not, dynamically.
for more information: 
[How To Check If A Method Exists At Runtime In Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058621/how-to-check-if-a-method-exists-at-runtime-in-java)

Comment: This is JavaScript, not Java?